# Departmental access to Sharepoint folders

Tags: document-library, permissions

I am new to the sharepoint. I have requirement that document library should have 2 Folders. One for Automotive and another for Healthcare.  Respective Teams sholud have read access to those folders. they must not see each other documents.
How to do this?
Thank you

Comment: For how to create a folder, see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-folder-in-a-document-library-3d6a8c11-2490-4d6b-8837-f25649a69c56?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). For how to set permissions, see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-and-manage-permissions-for-a-SharePoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple Dave !!

Go to site content of the site --> Add an app--> Document library.

For creating folders, open your library click Files --> New Folder

> (Repeat above process twice)

Then for permissions -->Select the folder -->Share--> Edit-->Advanced-->(Break inheritance if showing)Grant Permissions. Done

Comment: certainly it will be helpful. But you should also mention about Breaking the inheritence. bcoz this is how Dave is expecting!

Answer (score 0):

If there more users you could create groups with separate permission and then
**open the document library =>  Document Library Settings => Permission For the Document Library =>** then assign the created group or The User's those how need the access 
on assigning time there is an option **permission** you can add the user with desired permission .